# How to expose ASP.NET Web API to partners

Tags: security, asp.net-web-api2

We have a separate web api project which consists of REST end points consumed by our different web applications(ASP.NET ,Mobile, PHP etc).

Now we have a situation that we want to expose our some of API's with our partners. For example I want to expose 2 API's one will give all recipes in our system and other will give detail of each recipe. We want to implement some of kind of security so that they can be only used by our partners not by anyone else.

Can somebody suggest us what kind of security is best for this use case.

Comment: You can use token based authentication. I would suggest making a wrapper API that calls your API and secure that specifically for your partners. Partners can then be given API keys which they will exchange for token during authentication.

Comment: Thanks for replying to this post @Nkosi, so what I understand partners always have to send that token to each request to our API once we validate API keys but what if that token is hacked or partner share with  others, in that case our API will be accessible to others too.

Comment: Common practice is to give tokens a short lifespan and provide the ability to renew token when expired. You can provide the ability to reject tokens and you also the ability to reset partner API keys if compromised. if you really want to restrict partners and they will be accessing you API from their server side then you can go as far as restricting access via IP

Comment: Thanks for useful information @Nkosi.